# Functions from the integers to themselves that converge in every p-adic topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, cauchy-sequences, p-adic-number-theory

Let $f: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ be an arbitrary function. We can extend it to a function $f_p: \mathbb Z_p \to \mathbb Z_p $ if and only if $f(n) \to f(m) \in \mathbb Z_p$ as $n \to m \in \mathbb Z_p$. ($\mathbb Z_p$ denotes the p-adics).

Now, it is not hard to show that if $f$ arises from a linear recurrence relation, that is, it satisfies $$\sum_{k=0}^ma_kf(n+k) = 0 \text{    for all } n\gg 0$$
then, we can extend it to a function $f_p: \mathbb Z_p \to \mathbb Z_p$ for all primes $p$. This is because we can write $f(n) = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha\alpha^np_\alpha(n)$ for constants $c_\alpha,\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb Z}$ and polynomials $p_\alpha(n) \in \mathbb Z[n]$.

So we only need to check for $f(n) = \alpha^n, p(n)$ and that's easy enough.

**Question:** Are linear recurrences the only sequences for which we can extend it to the p-adics for every prime? Note that we only care about the eventual behavious of the sequences so we can modify as many initial terms as we want.

Comment: It's false that $ n \to \alpha^n $ is continuous in the $p$-adic topology. For instance, you have $ |2^{3^n} - 1|_3 = 1 $ for all $ n \geq 1 $.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I need to assume $\alpha \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Let me think about it in the context of my application.

Comment: You mean it can be extended *continuously*. Then Mahler bases might be useful. Concretely, according to https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mahlerexpansions.pdf (2.2/2.3) you'll need that $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} f(k)$ goes to $0$ for $n\to \infty$ in each $p$-adic value.

Comment: Conversely, if $a_n$ is any sequence that goes to $0$ in all $p$-adic values (trivial example: $a_n =0$ for large $n$; but also e.g. $a_1= 2, a_2 = 2^2\cdot 3, a_3=2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5, ...$), then $f(x)=\sum a_n \binom{x}{n}$ could be such a function; I'm not sure though if then $f(\mathbb Z) \subseteq \mathbb Z$ (whereas $f(\mathbb N) \subseteq \mathbb N$ is clear).